# Combinations of letters with restrictions

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

Create a string of five letters using the letters: `A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L, M`.

a) How many words contain at least one `A`?

b) How many words contain exactly two `A`'s?

For a) by my understanding is the total amount of combinations - the total amount of words without them. Which is what I believe to be $13^5 - 12^5$, however it feels as though it is too high/wrong

As for b), my train of thought is along the lines of:

$$\frac{13!}{2!\cdot 11!} \cdot \frac{12!}{3!\cdot 9!} \cdot \tfrac12$$

The first fraction is for the two `A`'s, the second fraction is for the letters in the other three positions and the half is to get rid of the doubles in the set. ie `AABCD` and `AABCD` where the `A`'s are swapped.

Answer (score 1):

The (a) part is correct. For the (b) part, think that indeed you must choose the places for putting the two $A$'s: $\binom{5}{2}$. Then, each of the other three places can be ocuped for any of the remaining 12 letters: $12^3$. So, the (b) answer is $\binom{5}{2}12^3$.

Comment: The English translation of restant is remaining.